# Find out the history of SQL queries

Tags: oracle, sql-update, database-administration

An update SQL query was executed on the server, which caused many problems later.

How can I get the list of update queries executed in last 2 months, so that I can trace the exact problematic SQL query?

Answer (score 87):

```
    select v.SQL_TEXT,
           v.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
           v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,
           v.DISK_READS,
           v.ROWS_PROCESSED,
           v.ELAPSED_TIME,
           v.service
      from v$sql v
where to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')>ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-2)
```

`where` clause is optional. You can sort the results according to FIRST_LOAD_TIME and find the records up to 2 months ago.

Comment: Many queries will have aged out of the shared_pool.  V$SQL will likely not have all the queries for the past 2 months.

Comment: I recently stumbled on this question and @JonHeller is correct.  `v$sql` doesn't go back far enough in time.  However, there is a view called `dba_hist_sqlstat` that may have the information you need.  You'll need to join the `snap_id` to `dba_hist_snapshot` to get the date though.

Answer (score 51):

For recent SQL:

```
select * from v$sql
```

For history:

```
select * from dba_hist_sqltext
```

Comment: Is there a way to find history with date?

Comment: select * from v$sql order by LAST_ACTIVE_TIME

Answer (score 14):

You can use this sql statement to get the history for any date:

```
SELECT * FROM V$SQL V where  to_date(v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') > sysdate - 60
```