# Recover SQL query results in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I worked on a bunch of queries yesterday, and before I could get to exporting the results to an external file, my database went down. Is there any way to see the results of your past few queries in SQL Developer? I know there are ways to see your past queries, but I am looking for the results of my queries. Finding them would save me and my team a lot of rework.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I am asking how to find the *results* of the SQL queries I ran yesterday. Not the queries themselves.

Comment: What did you do to SQL Developer when the DB went down? Then: What are your SQL Developer settings? Two of them in particular: How many rows of output do you show at a time? And: Do you show all query results in a single tab, a new query output overwriting the previous one? Or does each query open a new output tab? Both "favorable" settings (show many rows, and open a new tab for each query) are **not** the defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out the history of SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries)

Comment: bring your database back up - good luck with that - and then you can try flashback query - so you run the query again, but it runs as the data was when you ran them previously https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003

Comment: No it is not possible. SQLDeveloper doesn't save results of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SELECT` statement with an `AS OF` clause. This retrieves data as it existed at some point in the past.

For example, this query returns the record from current state for Chung.

```
SELECT * FROM employees
     WHERE last_name = 'Chung';
```

And below query retrieves the state of the record for Chung at 9:30AM, April 4, 2004:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
  AS OF TIMESTAMP
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
     WHERE last_name = 'Chung';
```

You can also restore like this:

```
INSERT INTO employees
  (SELECT * FROM employees
     AS OF TIMESTAMP
       TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
         WHERE last_name = 'Chung');
```

Drag the queries from SQL history to worksheet and modify with `AS OF` clause.
Refer to the source of this answer for more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1025568