# Oracle SP not populating data in a table through SSIS

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

I have an oracle SP which inserts data in the table.

When I am trying to run the oracle SP with no in and out parameter from SSIS execute SQL task it is running successfully but not populating any data in the table.

But When I am running the same SP in PL/SQL it is working absolutely fine and data is also populating in the table.

I have no clue what is going wrong

Comment: Did you COMMIT?

Comment: I have this in my execute sql task                                                              begin
  test;
end;

Comment: So, try with "BEGIN TEST; **COMMIT;** END;

Comment: still not working

Comment: I don't use SSIS so I'll have to ask: as SP works correctly when ran in Oracle, then I presume that there's something going on when called from SSIS. You said that it runs "successfully", i.e. no errors. Do you, by any chance, have some "error handler" in SSIS which does something like "WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL" (a quite stupid thing) in Oracle? You know - maybe it fails, but *something* prevents you from seeing an error.

Comment: Why do you mention "no in and out parameter from SSIS" - does the proc take parameters?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am not having any parameters in my SP

Comment: Sounds like there's no commit but normally that would be obvious because the table would be locked. Perhaps use this method to identify exactly what was submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries

Comment: DId you check if the user, which is executing the SSIS package, is the same as the one you use in PL/SQL? Might be some grants missing or something...

Comment: I checked and both the user is same.