# Get list of queries to oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I use EF and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to get/update/delete data from Oracle database.

How can I get history list of PL/SQL queries for this Oracle database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sql statement to get the history for any date:

```
SELECT * FROM V$SQL V where first_load_time LIKE '2015-05-04%';
```

Repeated: [Find out the history of SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries)

I don't know how to set the question as duplicated...

Comment: I got error: SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Maybe your user doesn’t have enough privileges to query that table

Comment: That requirement was not present in your original question. Try adding this filter to your query: `AND PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME='TEST'`

Comment: @Kirill All of the names starting with _V$_ are views to SYS tables  named _V_$_. So the table you need select privileges on would be _SYS.V_$SQL_.