# How to identify which user executed update statement on particular table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

So this is my scenario, Here I want to identify who updated my test table and I don't have access to sys.

is there any way to find out without using sys??

```
create table test
                 (
                  id      number,
                  name    varchar2(32767),
                  age     number
                 );

insert into test values(2,'XYZ',18);
insert into test values(3,'ABC',19);
```

Random User updated test table

```
update test set age =20 where id =3;
```

Comment: Please elaborate "user". Do you mean Oracle user (schema)?

Comment: yes ,@sohail schema user

Answer (score 3):

You can check `v$sql` and `v$session`. Below query will help you to get the session details.

```
select * from v$sql a join v$session b 
on a.sql_id = b.sql_id
where upper(b.sql_fulltext) like %UPDATE%your_table_name%;
```

You can check below links for more details.

`V$SESSION` - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223

`V$SQL` - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75.htm#REFRN30246

`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1007.htm#REFRN30299

Other Helping Links - [Find out the history of SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries)

**However, for the future, I suggest you follow the below steps for logging.**

1. Create a trigger on before update statement of the table.
2. Insert in the logs table, with two extra columns  (IP and HOST) with values`SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS', 15)` and `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST', 15)`.
3. This will provide IP and Hostname of the machine from which update was run.

You can check the output of the below queries.

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS', 15) ipaddr from dual;

select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST', 15) host_name from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, it's preferable to use a DB Trigger for DML operations for logging People and related Module Information. At the Application layer *Client* and *Module* Info might be set as :

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info( my_client_name ); 
dbms_application_info.set_module( my_mdl, null );
```

It's proper to create a table for logging for DML operations applied for the table `test` as :

```
create table test( col1 int, col2 varchar2(50) .... ); -- <-- assuming test is as this.
create table log_test( col1 int, col2 varchar2(50) ...., col_cl_info varchar2(64),
           col_terminal varchar2(64), col_opr_time date, col_machine varchar2(64), 
           col_dml_type varchar2(1) , col_module varchar2(64) );
```

and then, you may create such a trigger as follows :

```
create or replace trigger trg_log_test
  before update or insert on test   
  for each row    
declare
  v_cl_info  v$session.client_info%type;
  v_machine  v$session.machine%type;
  v_module   v$session.module%type;
  v_action   v$session.osuser%type;
  v_dml_type varchar2(1);
begin

  select client_info, machine, module
    into v_cl_info, v_machine, v_module
    from v$session
   where audsid = userenv('SESSIONID');


if v_cl_info in ('oracle') then 
 dbms_application_info.read_client_info( v_cl_info ); 
 dbms_application_info.read_module( v_module, v_action ); 
end if; 

if     inserting then 
  v_dml_type := 'I';
elsif  updating then
  v_dml_type := 'U';
end if;  

  insert into log_test( col1, col2, .... ,
         col_cl_info, col_terminal, col_opr_time , col_machine, col_dml_type, col_module )
  values(:new.col1, :new.col2, .........., 
         v_cl_info , userenv('TERMINAL'),sysdate , v_machine , v_dml_type , v_module  );

end;
```

where *v$session* is a *public synonym* for *sys.v_$session* dictionary view.