# creating a ChangeLog mechanism in apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I need to keep track of every create/edit/delete operation made by Apex users in my application, for that I have created a table in my database : LOG

```
CREATE TABLE LOG
    ( id    NUMBER
    , USER_NAME     VARCHAR2(20)
    , TIMESTAMP     DATE  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    , QUERY         VARCHAR2(255)
    , TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2(30)
    ) ;
```

I don't know if it is possible to return the SQL query but I can replace that with the type of the operation executed.
now is that possible to do this in apex without having to add +100 triggers/page processes in all of my database table/pages. I've heard someone saying that QuickSQL in apex SQL Workshop can help but I don't know how.

Comment: to begin with: yes you can return executed queries. here is an explanation on how  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831835/5629432

Comment: This sounds more like a job for FDA https://www.insum.ca/use-flashback-data-archive-instead-of-journaling-tables/